# React Native - (IOS) How to keep the application running in the background?

Tags: ios, react-native, geolocation, location, background-process

I`m developing a fitness app in react native, but I couldn't get the app to keep running in the background on ios (to get the user's geolocation).

I managed it on Android, but I am struggling with ios. Every library I tried, stopped working in the background after a while

Does somebody knows how I can do this?

I will appreciate a lot if somebody help me :)

I tried to use libraries like react-native-background-timer and react-native-background-actions

Comment: On iOS you can't use timers or other methods to keep the app running in the background. If you are using location services then your app needs to specify the location background mode and activate background location updates. Location updates will then be delivered to your application periodically when it is suspended, causing it to run, briefly, in the background so you can process the updates.

Comment: Hi @Paulw11 thanks for the reply

I have enabled Background Processing and Location Updates modes in XCode.
Could you please specify and/or give me an example of how I can get the location updates in the background in my React Native app? 
I need this information because I am developing a fitness app and need to show the user their speed, calories burned, distance and their track on the map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for your help! I found a way to get the user`s geolocation and do some operations in background using the library react-native-geolocation-service
There is a method called watchPosition that will give you the user's location frequently. As I understand it here, it will not always run at a specific interval, but will continue to run in the background until you stop the service.

You just need to configure your XCode enabling Background Modes and Location Updates on Capabilities